# node.js https pfx certificate error

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, cryptojs

I am trying to send a request to a HTTPS server by attaching a .pfx certificate along with the passphrase. However, I am getting this error:

```
crypto.js:145
  c.context.loadPKCS12(pfx);
            ^
Error: wrong tag
at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:145:17)
at Object.exports.connect (tls.js:1331:27)
at Object.createConnection (https.js:79:14)
at new ClientRequest (http.js:1428:26)
at Object.exports.request (https.js:123:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\srmocher\Desktop\Webspaces.js:10:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Here is my code:

```
var https=require('https');
var options={
    hostname:'https://<my-api>'
    method:'GET',
    pfx:"<pfx-data>",
    passphrase:"<pass>",
    agent:false
};
var req=https.request(options,function(res){
    res.on('data',function(d){
        console.log(d);
    })
});
```

If anyone can help me understand the error, I'd be glad.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html
This might help..!

Comment: I've checked that. But this error seems specific to Crypto.JS.

Comment: ok let me do some research in this then and you do the same..As soon i get an answer i'll post it here..

Comment: Because I just had the same problem during development, I stumbled across [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026880/p12-certificate-not-enough-data-error/37300058#37300058). Are you sure, you are passing file-contents of the pfx and not the string?